# Дополнительная обработка входящих данных

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Подскажите пожалуйста, используя `YII2` во время получения `post` запроса защищает ли `Yii::$app->request-post('login')` от сторонних запросов или все же нужно проверять на символы например одинарной кавычки,или если число на число и тд, или при использование `ActiveRecord` или `Yii::$app->db->createCommand()` можно не париться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз никто не хочет помогать Вам, отвечу я `:]`

Возможно вы не совсем понимаете то, от чего вы хотите защититься.

`Yii::$app->request-post('login')`

Можно переписать так:

`isset($_POST['login']) ? $_POST['login'] : null;`

Как видите никакой фильтрации тут нет.

Обычно фильтруют от `XSS`, в `Yii2` есть `HtmlPurifier::process` (документация тут - [тык](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtmlpurifier))

---

Теперь по `Yii::$app->db->createCommand()`:

`XSS` и `SQL-Injection` - 2 разные вещи. Поэтому защищаясь от одного, вы не защищены от второго.

`createCommand()`- это прям аналог `PDO`, только расширенный, все тоже самое, для защиты от инъекций используются `bindParam` и `bindValue`